# How do i write algorithm for Map and Regex together to check inputs?

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to have an input as such

```
final String input = "one=1&two=2";
```

And I am using a Map method

```
public Map<String, String> decode(String s) {
    if(!s.isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            s.split("&");
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck here ,trying to write the algorithm that will check a string such as the one I wrote above and return mapping like

```
 ("one", "1");
 ("two", "2");
```

I wrote a regex like this `^[a-z0-9 +=][{1,}]$`

Comment: 1) Thre is no point to iterate over the string. 2) Keep it simple and just split string with "&" and then with "=".

Comment: And how do I return the value to give the desired result

Comment: The linked duplicate answer has the necessary code for you. Look at the `splitQuery` method.